# Differencing VHD devours disk

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

My differencing VHD is taking up almost all space on my physical hard drive. I have not much data on my XP32 environment which is being emulated by W7-64; so it's a puzzle to me.

Please suggest a course of action which would reduce the VHD size (preferably w/o killing my data on it) or at least prevent further unneeded consumption.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the XP SP3 parent drive in the first place?

Biggest thing you can do is just reduce the amount of files you store in XP mode, since Virtual PC allows you access to the host PC through network shares.

Comment: The C drive in the virtual has 113GB free of 126GB (there are mostly xml and textfiles - outside the OS). The main machine has 48MB left, out of 232GB.